# Block code in a method does not get run

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have the code below to load a group of images and notify me via completionHandler when they are all done loading.  However, I find that certain dispatch_group_leave won't be called at times and my guess is imageLoader is deallocated before the block gets to run.  If I put a reference of imageLoader within the loadImageWithURL:completionHandler block, then everything works as intended.

Is my guess of the cause correct? What's the correct fix for this issue? I know ARC does block copy in most cases automatically, should I do a block copy in this case?

```
- (void)loadGroupImagesAsyncWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSError *))completionHandler {

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    int index = 0;

    for (Item *item in items) {

        char queueLabel[30] = {0};
        sprintf(queueLabel, "loader%d", index);
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(queueLabel, NULL);

        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{

          ImageLoader *imageLoader = [[ImageLoader alloc] init];
          [imageLoader loadImageWithURL:url completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
              if (image) {
                 item.image = image;
              }

              //NOTE: if item object is referenced in this block, 
              //then there is no missed dispatch_group_leave call.
              dispatch_group_leave(group);
          }];
        });
    }

    // Non-blocking wait
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // shouldn't take more than 5 secs to load all images
        dispatch_group_wait(group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)));
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler(nil);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: just an advice... the theories of _shouldn't take more than X secs..._ are always broken when there is problem with the network connection and it becomes slow. you _cannot_ predict the necessary time in practice.

Comment: How do handle connection errors? Can you add the code for your `ImageLoader`, especifically this method `loadImageWithURL:completionHandler:`?

Comment: @holex If the network is down it will kick off reachability code somewhere else, so we are covered there.  It's fine if the assumption is wrong, we will just give it default image - it's better to do this than to have users wait forever.

Comment: @lucianomarisi Connection error is handled, that's not the focus of this question though.

Comment: @Boon, the _slow-network_ is not equal to _network-is-down_. those are two different scenarios, so you are not really covered here at all.

Comment: @Boon, one way or another (success or failure of the connection) your `dispatch_group_leave(group);` should get executed then.

Comment: @holex I am covered by using default image as mentioned.  Having users wait is not acceptable.  If you don't mind, I would like to bring our attention back to the question and leave error handling for a different thread.

Comment: @lucianomarisi As mentioned - it doesn't unless I reference the item object within the block, which seems to keep the block alive.

Comment: @holex Thanks, it's not helpful because that's not what I am asking.  There is no mess, everything is taken care of on the error handling side of things.  Please focus on the question.

Comment: @Boon How do you guarantee this "shouldn't take more than 5 secs to load all images"?

Comment: @lucianomarisi I don't want to guarantee - I will display default image if it doesn't come back by then.

Comment: Looks like `imageLoader` is getting deallocated before `completionHandler` is called. Also you doesn't use instance of `ImageLoader` anywhere. You better define `loadImageWithURL:completionHandler:` as class method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess. It's only a guess because you haven't posted the code of anything to do with ImageLoader.

If `-loadImageWithURL:completionHandler:` operates asynchronously i.e. it uses an async dispatch queue itself then you could be right that it is being deallocated before the load finishes.  This is because its lifetime is just the scope of the for block it is declared in.

In fact, there is no reason why that method needs to do stuff asynchronously, because you have already got it in an asynchronous block.  Just have a synchronous method and call `dispatch_group_leave()` after the method finishes.

**EDIT**

Given that you have no control over ImageLoader and `-loadImageWithURL:completionHandler:` operates asynchronously without any help from you, you should remove the `dispatch_async` wrapper around the call.  You'll still have the problem of the ImageLoader being deallocated, but that can be avoided by putting each ImageLoader in a array when you create it.

The code would look something like this:

```
- (void)loadGroupImagesAsyncWithCompletion:(void(^)(NSError *))completionHandler 
{

    NSMutableArray* loaders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
    int index = 0;

    for (Item *item in items) {

        char queueLabel[30] = {0};
        sprintf(queueLabel, "loader%d", index);
        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create(queueLabel, NULL);

        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        ImageLoader *imageLoader = [[ImageLoader alloc] init];
        [imageLoader loadImageWithURL:url completionHandler:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {
            if (image) {
               item.image = image;
            }

              //NOTE: if item object is referenced in this block, 
              //then there is no missed dispatch_group_leave call.
              dispatch_group_leave(group);
        }];
        [loaders addObject: imageLoader];
    }

    // Non-blocking wait
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // shouldn't take more than 5 secs to load all images
        dispatch_group_wait(group, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)));
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            completionHandler(nil);
        });
        [loaders removeAllObjects];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ImageLoader is a third party code, so at this point I am using it as is, which is async.

Comment: @Boon amended the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks. Will the extra dispatch_async around ImageLoader hurt? Just in case if future version of loadImage changes behavior this code can still work.

Comment: @Boon I don't think so, as long as you maintain the references to the ImageLoaders until your non blocking wait.